# different digest value in xml in java

Tags: java, c#, xml, digital-signature, digital-certificate

```
public void finalMethod(String originalXmlFilePath,String destnSignedXmlFilePath)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableEntryException, KeyStoreException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, CertificateException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, MarshalException, XMLSignatureException, TransformerException {

    // Create a DOM XMLSignatureFactory that will be used to
    // generate the enveloped signature.
    XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

    // Create a Reference to the enveloped document (in this case,
    // you are signing the whole document, so a URI of "" signifies
    // that, and also specify the SHA1 digest algorithm and
    // the ENVELOPED Transform.
    Reference ref = fac.newReference
     ("", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
      Collections.singletonList
       (fac.newTransform
        (Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null)),
         null, null);

    // Create the SignedInfo.
    SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo
     (fac.newCanonicalizationMethod
      (CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE,
       (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
        fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null),
         Collections.singletonList(ref));




    KeyStore p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
    p12.load(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/prakhar.s/Downloads/JAVA DIGITAL/New folder (2)/TestDigCertificate/TestCertForLOBA.pfx"),"1234".toCharArray());
    Enumeration e = p12.aliases();
    String alias = (String) e.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Cert alias:" + alias);
    //Key privateKey = p12.getKey(alias, "1234".toCharArray());
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) p12.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("1234".toCharArray()));
    //Certificate cert =  keyEntry.getCertificate(); 





    // Load the KeyStore and get the signing key and certificate.
   X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();


    // Create the KeyInfo containing the X509Data.
    KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();



    ArrayList x509Content = new ArrayList();

    //x509Content.add(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());



    String dn = cert.getIssuerDN().toString();
    BigInteger sn = cert.getSerialNumber();



    BigInteger bigsn2 = new BigInteger (1, sn.toByteArray());
    System.out.println("new bigint (decimal): " + bigsn2);
    System.out.println("new bigint (hex): " + bigsn2.toString(16));




    X509IssuerSerial xd1 = kif.newX509IssuerSerial(dn, bigsn2);

    x509Content.add(xd1);
    x509Content.add(cert);
    X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);

    KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));

    // Instantiate the document to be signed.



    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse
        (new FileInputStream(originalXmlFilePath));





    // Create a DOMSignContext and specify the RSA PrivateKey and
    // location of the resulting XMLSignature's parent element.
    DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext
        (keyEntry.getPrivateKey(), doc.getDocumentElement());

    // Create the XMLSignature, but don't sign it yet.
    XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);

    // Marshal, generate, and sign the enveloped signature.
    signature.sign(dsc);













    storeSignedDoc(doc, destnSignedXmlFilePath);


}
```

Above is method that I am using to sign a xml file in Java. Below is the sample xml that have been signed in .net

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>

-<BharatKoshPayment Version="1.0" DepartmentCode="020">


-<Submit>


-<OrderBatch merchantBatchCode="e178eb86ce3dfa4b3f6a" Transactions="1" TotalAmount="1">


-<Order OrderCode="e178eb86ce3dfa4b3f6a" InstallationId="10011">


-<CartDetails>

<Description/>

<Amount value="1" exponent="0" CurrencyCode="INR"/>

<OrderContent>725</OrderContent>

<PaymentTypeId>294</PaymentTypeId>

<PAOCode>027973</PAOCode>

<DDOCode>227987</DDOCode>

</CartDetails>


-<PaymentMethodMask>

<Include Code="Online"/>

</PaymentMethodMask>


-<Shopper>

<ShopperEmailAddress>prachiebooks@gmail.com</ShopperEmailAddress>

</Shopper>


-<ShippingAddress>


-<Address>

<FirstName>PRACHI INDIA Pvt.Ltd.</FirstName>

<LastName/>

<Address1>INDER LOK DELHI-110035</Address1>

<Address2/>

<PostalCode>110035</PostalCode>

<City>West Delhi</City>

<StateRegion>New Delhi</StateRegion>

<State>New Delhi</State>

<CountryCode>India</CountryCode>

<MobileNumber>7042112623</MobileNumber>

</Address>

</ShippingAddress>


-<BillingAddress>


-<Address>

<FirstName>PRACHI INDIA Pvt.Ltd.</FirstName>

<LastName/>

<Address1>INDER LOK DELHI-110035</Address1>

<Address2/>

<PostalCode>110035</PostalCode>

<City>West Delhi</City>

<StateRegion>New Delhi</StateRegion>

<State>New Delhi</State>

<CountryCode>India</CountryCode>

<MobileNumber>7042112623</MobileNumber>

</Address>

</BillingAddress>

<StatementNarrative>Publication Divisions Payment </StatementNarrative>

</Order>

</OrderBatch>

</Submit>


-<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">


-<SignedInfo>

<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>

<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>


-<Reference URI="">


-<Transforms>

<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>

</Transforms>

<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>

<DigestValue>QnaBNlOrLTHe9UMU2dyAJZ1DXFI=</DigestValue>

</Reference>

</SignedInfo>

<SignatureValue>QCBsnlKP1udt1eAtdk1b1VxP/bq4wnKpnEblvbSGPk4lJKNkC+TjfUbYdKSDtypLdCIldQox/x3jCmNJZVxRqtPlSYyeC/xOlrbA2ya5svGtH9fw7+wkHyzcGPtjoJKGhHTrfTDbMVMNxCe6Ph+OZEZuTm8LLWAzl9UcMEeZAUk=</SignatureValue>


-<KeyInfo>


-<X509Data>


-<X509IssuerSerial>

<X509IssuerName>CN=TestCertForLOBA</X509IssuerName>

<X509SerialNumber>180518423413430116130326665604242149948</X509SerialNumber>

</X509IssuerSerial>

<X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>

</X509Data>

</KeyInfo>

</Signature>

</BharatKoshPayment>
```

Below is my Java generated signed xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<BharatKoshPayment Version="1.0" DepartmentCode="020">


-<Submit>


-<OrderBatch merchantBatchCode="e178eb86ce3dda4b3f6a" Transactions="1" TotalAmount="1">


-<Order OrderCode="e178eb86ce3dda4b3f6a" InstallationId="10011">


-<CartDetails>

<Description/>

<Amount value="1" exponent="0" CurrencyCode="INR"/>

<OrderContent>725</OrderContent>

<PaymentTypeId>294</PaymentTypeId>

<PAOCode>027973</PAOCode>

<DDOCode>227987</DDOCode>

</CartDetails>


-<PaymentMethodMask>

<Include Code="Online"/>

</PaymentMethodMask>


-<Shopper>

<ShopperEmailAddress>prachiebooks@gmail.com</ShopperEmailAddress>

</Shopper>


-<ShippingAddress>


-<Address>

<FirstName>PRACHI INDIA Pvt.Ltd.</FirstName>

<LastName/>

<Address1>INDER LOK DELHI-110035</Address1>

<Address2/>

<PostalCode>110035</PostalCode>

<City>West Delhi</City>

<StateRegion>New Delhi</StateRegion>

<State>New Delhi</State>

<CountryCode>India</CountryCode>

<MobileNumber>7042112623</MobileNumber>

</Address>

</ShippingAddress>


-<BillingAddress>


-<Address>

<FirstName>PRACHI INDIA Pvt.Ltd.</FirstName>

<LastName/>

<Address1>INDER LOK DELHI-110035</Address1>

<Address2/>

<PostalCode>110035</PostalCode>

<City>West Delhi</City>

<StateRegion>New Delhi</StateRegion>

<State>New Delhi</State>

<CountryCode>India</CountryCode>

<MobileNumber>7042112623</MobileNumber>

</Address>

</BillingAddress>

<StatementNarrative>Publication Divisions Payment </StatementNarrative>

</Order>

</OrderBatch>

</Submit>


-<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">


-<SignedInfo>

<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>

<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>


-<Reference URI="">


-<Transforms>

<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>

</Transforms>

<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>

<DigestValue>2/bkZpFjH4VQZXSIfugosld9T9I=</DigestValue>

</Reference>

</SignedInfo>

<SignatureValue>PVFjdC3dwhNUGa3GBKQTkcpUbdUkdNvzA3S3pLT9S0rNsyDAVcY2qW76+qaXn7aFkPBIyQlg2ikU qlizmo2WaAgZlMkBLcPdpp/wzXBUih10yyxgI9+ExuNZ3z1DqOoEZHVT6/IJlcz2iKyutSvl7a+1 P6dYO0ndT2j9izACbV0=</SignatureValue>


-<KeyInfo>


-<X509Data>


-<X509IssuerSerial>

<X509IssuerName>CN=TestCertForLOBA</X509IssuerName>

<X509SerialNumber>180518423413430116130326665604242149948</X509SerialNumber>

</X509IssuerSerial>

<X509Certificate>MIICFTCCAYKgAwIBAgIQh86VbnKj77tMYlZ5PHkSPDAJBgUrDgMCHQUAMBoxGDAWBgNVBAMTD1Rl c3RDZXJ0Rm9yTE9CQTAeFw0xNTEyMzExODMwMDBaFw0xNzAzMzAxODMwMDBaMBoxGDAWBgNVBAMT D1Rlc3RDZXJ0Rm9yTE9CQTCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAqH1D3ycqoUs1N/+p r+xCXtrAhwJWf4XHXM/tNtvuJ/BLfwH8C4kji9TfZz/4PLvF/j5DJO22Pmv2iPYeKGWmrq0y7b8O ++3zTcgO800/gFdM8GztW1E+FUwRq5A7D0UXlxUs7ePib0K4zWOyYOMlf28NYzFD5/qTnYBYjymf HkcCAwEAAaNkMGIwEwYDVR0lBAwwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwEwSwYDVR0BBEQwQoAQ3Nw37mdOlicLkYm1 Kw9DTqEcMBoxGDAWBgNVBAMTD1Rlc3RDZXJ0Rm9yTE9CQYIQh86VbnKj77tMYlZ5PHkSPDAJBgUr DgMCHQUAA4GBAGwurrSEfqVIGnsTyXF5TRbdqEbsSazoFhTWlLLMupPAc2Xmvp5lmMH76TYG/Zsx 9wsZK5cjP/GNBvKLXPtfkElQHFztHotoU29Y9QqNIx5xBX02CJpuDeWm27OjPI39JbgfPBNFyoRI ZIBNcQP2tUXd8JYh/FxXOj/xhfY2OlKp</X509Certificate>

</X509Data>

</KeyInfo>

</Signature>

</BharatKoshPayment>
```

My problem is , I am getting mismatch digest value in java.

I also have .net code for generating signed xml

```
public XmlDocument signedFun(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
{
    string CertificateKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CDSCOHealthKey"].ToString();
    X509Store certificate = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

    if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["isLocalPdfSign"] != null && ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["isLocalPdfSign"].ToString() == "True")
    {
        certificate = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    }
    certificate.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = null;
    X509Certificate2 certx = new X509Certificate2();
    foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in certificate.Certificates)
    {
        if (cert.Subject.Contains(CertificateKey))
        {
            // retrieve private key                  
            rsaKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
            certx = cert;
            break;
        }
    }


    if (rsaKey == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Valid certificate was not found");

    }

    // Sign the XML document. 
    if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsNewsXMLSign"] == "True")
    {
        SignXml(xmlDoc, rsaKey, certx);
    }
    return xmlDoc;
}
public static void SignXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc, RSA Key, X509Certificate2 Cert)
{
    // Check arguments. 
    if (xmlDoc == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("xmlDoc");
    if (Key == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Key");

    // Create a SignedXml object.
    System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml signedXml = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml(xmlDoc);
    // SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

    // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
    signedXml.SigningKey = Key;
    // *** Create a KeyInfo structure
    KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
    // *** Specifically use the issuer and serial number for the data rather than the default
    KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoData = new KeyInfoX509Data();
    keyInfoData.AddIssuerSerial(Cert.Issuer, Cert.GetSerialNumberString());
    keyInfoData.AddCertificate(Cert);

    keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoData);


    // *** provide the certficate info that gets embedded - note this is only
    // *** for specific formatting of the message to provide the cert info
    signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

    // Create a reference to be signed.
    Reference reference = new Reference();
    reference.Uri = "";

    // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
    XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
    reference.AddTransform(env);

    // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
    signedXml.AddReference(reference);

    // Compute the signature.
    signedXml.ComputeSignature();

    // Get the XML representation of the signature and save 
    // it to an XmlElement object.
    XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

    // Append the element to the XML document.
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

}
```

Any One have solution ??

Comment: Your question is mostly code, try adding some descriptions, especially at the start of your question.

Comment: Go through this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203828/sign-xml-in-java-referencing-from-c-sharp

Comment: Any new ? I have the same problem